# Why doesn't my date field work in a session?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I do this in my controller:

```
def new
    @army = Army.new(strength: session[:last_army_strength], 
                     type_id: session[:last_type]),
                     date: session[:last_date])
end

def create
    @army = current_user.armies.new(params[:army])
    session[:last_army_strength] = params[:army][:strength]
    session[:last_type] = params[:army][:type_id]
    session[:last_date] = params[:army][:date]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @army.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_army_path, :notice => "New army added" }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `type_id` and `strength` fields are saved but my `date` field resets itself. Why is this?

Comment: This may be unrelated, but shouldnt that be `current_user.armies.build`, not new

Comment: @AJcodez Right you are, prob why I was having another issue, thanks.

Comment: what you mean by resets itself? in the new or create method?

Comment: @Rogier What I mean by resets itself is that it creates a new form basically and doesn't bring up last form's `date`.

Comment: OK. so its about loading the defaults? Can you log session[:last_date].class (see what it class it is)? You should also paste some of the form.